# Showing Description in label but saving the primary key for it

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

**Happy New Year!**

I want to place a `label` in a `KendoUI Grid` , When my page loads I am passing in the primary key of some table that refers to the description of the value I show in the label.  It is working good when the page loads, BUT when I go to add a new row to the grid, it switches back and shows the primary key value in there.

Here is parts of how I have it currently setup:

In the `schema` of the grid I have added two fields:

```
                        ManagerPK: {
                            type: "number",
                            defaultValue : SearchVariable
                        },
                        ManagerName: {
                            type: "string"
                        }
```

And my Create/Update of the Kendo Grid are defined like this:

```
                create: {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "AddSomeRow",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json"
                },
                update: {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "UpdateSomeRow",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json"
                },
```

and in the columns definition of the grid for it I defined it like this:

columns: [

```
{
    field: "ManagerPK",
    title: "Manager Desc",
    width: "8%",
    template: "#=ManagerDesc ? ManagerDesc : ''#"
}
```

So how should I change my code to NOT SHOW the `PK` and always she the **Description**?

Comment: Please attach a screen shot of the grid and how it is currently being displayed.

Comment: What about this template: `"#=data.ManagerDesc ? ManagerDesc : ManagerPK#"` ? Side note: use `data.` in the condition to avoid runtime errors.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle of your code?